# Why do we always check if input fails but not output?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why do we always do this

```
if (cin >> var)
```

but never do this

```
if (cout << var)
```

Aren't we suppose to check if it succeeded or not?

Comment: @NPE Users in general.

Comment: What are you going to do if output fails? Print an error message?

Comment: @RaymondChen Throw an exception.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Exit with an error code instead of continuing to produce broken output.

Comment: But nobody will see the error code either because by definition output is broken.

Comment: @RaymondChen: there are multiple output channels.  Just because one is broken doesn't mean the others are.  It's quite easy to build a shell script that has a bad output pipe but which is still fully capable of checking return codes, and the error pipe might be working just fine.  Not worth checking for `cout` failure for the vast majority of console apps (where the output is usually just status updates or the like anyway), but there definitely are use cases that need to check for output failure.

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch Given the nature of the question, it was clear that we were talking about simple programs where all that happens is that some data is read from `cin` and a result is generated to `cout`. For more complex scenarios checking for output failure is naturally appropriate.

Comment: @RaymondChen: of course.  I was replying to the comment that nobody can use an error return code because output is broken (which is not true), not the sentiment in general.  For simple programs it would clearly be a waste of time and energy to handle `cout` failure. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy to generate End Of File on input. For example, the input might come from a file. Or an interactive user might indicate EOF in some command interpreter specific way (e.g. Ctrl Z in Windows, or Ctrl D in *nix).

Generally that causes input failure.

For `cin >> var` which is formatted input, there can also be failure to interpret the input text as a specification of a value of the relevant type.

None of this applies to output.

Output can fail, but generally only due to pretty catastrophic reasons such as the storage unit becoming full.

Answer (score 4):

The premise is wrong: not all writes go unchecked.

As an example of checked writes, consider a database. Before answering OK to a commit request, a database will generally ensure that the data has been correctly written to disk or duplicated (and acknowledged) to another instance.

Therefore, it is less that software does check writes, and more than writes are checked differently than reads: a failed read mean that the program cannot continue (in general) because it is lacking data; on the other hand, the program can continue after a failed write for it already has the data!

Thus, the only writes that are checked are those which the program guarantee to check, such as the database writes to a hard-disk that ensure the durability of the data that the software promises. On the other hand, writes to log files or console screens are rarely (if ever) checked: log files are generally not supposed to get in the way (and they are logged asynchronously) and if a write to the console screen fails the user will likely replay the command anyway or the next program in the pipe will fail itself...

Answer (score 0):

The input is something that the program has not control over.

For example humans are not that accurate at typing. You can therefore get the program to take steps to either get the user to have another go etc.

As for output you can check. But to the human it is self evident that something is amiss. This is not true when writing to files but output to the screen it is. If you cannot write output to the console what can you do?

Comment: Terminate with an error code, rather than continuing a 30h calculation whose only evident result is supposed to be console output. But, then, this would probably be a counter-example where you _may_ indeed see output checking.